# Php Mailer Not Working on live server but working on local host :(

Tags: php, phpmailer, liveserver

This is the Code , its working on local host
but not working on live server

isSMTP(); i already remove it on live server but still dosent work

```
    require 'phpmalier/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $email = new PHPMailer;
    //$email->isSMTP();
    $email->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $email->Port=587;
    $email->SMTPAuth=true;
    $email->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $email->Username='exmapile@gmail.com';
    $email->Password='*******';
    $email->SetFrom('exmpile@gmail.com');
    $email->AddAddress('exmpile@gmail.com');
    $email->isHtml(True);
    $email->Subject= $mail . 'Contact Form';
    $email->Body= $user .'<br>'. $phone . '<br>' . $msg;
```

Comment: Please [search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+local+server). You're using a very old version of PHPMailer too, so update.

Comment: Thanks For let me know its old , but if i found the answer i will not post :) any way thanks